# Why is my output printing null when the Queue has data?

Tags: java, queue

I am trying to get a program to print out an answer to an equation x times based on two range variables. I created a queue variable that will hold an equation before it enters my for loop. In my for loop I created a backup version of the queue because when I send it to another method it removes values from that queue, eventually leaving me with an empty queue. I use that backup in the method and then just redeclare it to the original queue at the top of the for loop.

My problem is, it works once giving me the desired output, however, each time after, it prints out null. My guess is because it thinks the queue is empty but I dont understand why. Below is my code of my main file, should be enough.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Infix Expression: ");
    String expression = keyboard.nextLine();
    GenericQueue<Token> result = new GenericQueue<Token>();

    Scanner keyboard2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Range: ");
    String range = keyboard2.nextLine();

    int start = 0;
    int end = 5;
    String var = "x";

    Process.toPostfix(expression, result);

    for (int i=start; i<=end; i++) {
        GenericQueue<Token> backup_result = result;
        System.out.println(backup_result.toString());
        Rational answer = Process.evaluate(backup_result, i, var);
        System.out.println(i + "    " + answer);
    }

    keyboard.close();
    keyboard2.close();
    }
}
```

and here is my output:

```
    Infix Expression: (5+x)
Range: f
 5 x +
0    5

1    null

2    null

3    null

4    null

5    null
```

Comment: You never added anything to the queue. You created it and never added any elements, which is why it is empty.

Comment: @Afforess the queue is getting added to in `.toPostfix()`. You can see this because the first iteration of the loop is printing out the full queue. The problem is that the queue isn't being copied at all, as I've explained further in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you write

```
GenericQueue<Token> backup_result = result;
```

you're not actually copying the queue, but just a *reference* to it. Any changes you make to `result` will be reflected in `backup_result`, and vice versa. You only ever have one queue, with two names.

This is only one of the problems... The other is that if you need to copy the queue into a backup then you're thinking the wrong way about queues: they're designed for one part of your code to put things into it, and another to remove them and deal with them.

Comment: Oh okay, that makes sense. Any tips then to do what Im trying to do? Im trying to use that queue multiple times

Comment: @l00kitsjake I think a queue is just the wrong datatype. Try putting them into a `List` instead, which you can then iterate over as many times as you like.